# FLTK, wxWidgets, GTK - light, easy and portable

Tags: c++, c, gtk, wxwidgets, fltk

I know that it isn't first topic when somebody considering different GUI libraries. But I have a few specific questions and needs that "the others" didn't have.

(As usual) I'm novice programmer, learning C++ now (finishing thinking in c++) and my university wants me to learn some GUI for programming projects (I'm electronics student) - I'm writing this because personally I would like to know C++ a little bit better before learning some additional libraries. But reality is brutal in this case :).

I'm looking for **simple** (easy to write in) library that will work under **windows, linux and embedded systems** (embedded linux or any other lightweight ARM system, not necessary android) without much (best case - ANY) modifications. I would like this library to be **lightweight** (thats why I eliminated QT), **easy to use with other libraries** (for audio/video players or some network applications) **and languages** (I'd like to write also in C, which will be my primary language I believe, maybe some python, D or java). The documentation/tutorials should be also easy and simply written - my English skills are very basic, as you can see reading my post.

After googling for hours my vote is for GTK/GTKmm which allow me to use LXDE, XFCE and GNOME (light/medium/heavy) without installing additional libraries, write code in C, C++, D, Python, Java and almost every programming language that exists. On the other hand many peoples wrote that FLTK is very simple, most portable and probably the fastest one. WxWidgets has many positive opinions so... I just don't know, please help me.

Thanks for your replies,

Pawel

Comment: Sorry, we can't help you. If there had been a single correct answer to this, you would already have found that. As you *have* found, different people have different opinions on this, and *you* will have to decide what's the best fit for you.

Comment: I believe there is a single correct answer if I have demands like posted above... QUESTION is : will FLTK handle my requirements or won't it? I'm looking for the lightest, simple GUI, there CAN NOT be 2 lightest one that will do the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard that FLTK is lightweight but have never used so no much comments. I have used however GTK+ and wxWidgets. I would say go for wxWidgets as it is a wrapper around GTK+ in Linux. Apart from that here are added advantages

- wxWidgets uses native widgets wherever possible
- You can use wxBase library which makes it lightweight (at expense of some feature see [this](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_libs.html#page_libs_wxbase))
- Great support than GTK+ IMHO (forum, IRC,  mailing list, SO, et al)

Also you can read these entries

1. http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_libs.html
2. http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141116/choosing-between-qt-gtk-and-wxwidgets
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257894/wxwindows-vs-gtk-for-cross-platform-gui-programming
5. http://www.gidforums.com/showpost.php?p=37761&postcount=8

I would personally suggest you go with wxWidgets!

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thanks!I'll probably go for wxwidgets then, GUI isn't as hard to learn as C++(which is horribly more complicated than C) so if it will go wrong with Wx I'll try sth else. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: All the best. Remember the forum and mailing list are your best friend! You can upvote if it helped you lol!

Comment: This question has been closed because two people won't have the same opinion on the topic. I used MFC, GTK+ and wxWidgets, and the one I prefer is GTK. wxWidgets is a mess that adds a layer of bugs above the toolkit of the native platform (it uses GTK+ on Linux). However GTK 3 is not really supported under Windows. I also think you removed Qt too soon. It is used in embedded, has better portability than GTK, and is not the horible mess wxWidgets is. [EFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_Foundation_Libraries) is lightweight, but I don't think it runs under Windows.

Comment: what do you mean when you say wx is mess? wx is not buggy as you paint. I use it for years now and bugs are quickly fixed as they rise. In fact I use SVN version for my app and is quiet stable and not buggy. can you elaborate it. Else you have said it well!